# Header Check Box in DataGridView

Tags: powershell

can anyone show me an example on how to add header check box in a datagridview with powershell? I am searching on the web with similar example but i can find one. I am trying to create a select all checkbox 
Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

```
$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$dataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGrid1.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 20,90
$dataGrid1.size = New-Object Drawing.Point 260,200
$dataGrid1.MultiSelect = $false
$dataGrid1.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$dataGrid1.RowHeadersVisible = $false
$datagridviewcheckboxcolumn1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn'

$dataGrid1.Columns.Add($datagridviewcheckboxcolumn1) | Out-Null
$form.Controls.Add($dataGrid1)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`$datagridview1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
$Col1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn'`

```
# datagridview1
$datagridview1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 'AutoSize'
[void]$datagridview1.Columns.Add($Col1)
$datagridview1.Dock = 'Fill'
$datagridview1.Location = '0, 0'
$datagridview1.Name = "datagridview1"
$datagridview1.Size = '284, 262'
$datagridview1.TabIndex = 0

# Col1
$Col1.HeaderText = "Add Header Here"
$Col1.Name = "Add Name Here"`
```

Comment: thanks for your comment HiTech but it is still not showing on the header. Anyway, i already did a workaround to check all the boxes when clicking on the header for this.

Comment: @JohnMiguel Could you post your solution then?